# Referencing same model twice in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models (Page and Image) in a rails API with a many to many relationship connecting them. I want to be able to reference the Image model (via image_ids: []) in two (and eventually more) places on my Page model.

I want both an "images gallery" array and a "featured image" array to be returned, I have what will be the gallery working as it should right now but I am struggling with understanding where to go from here. Is this even possible?

I feel like this should not be as complicated as I am making it, so I would really appreciate any help- I'm quite a new developer and new to rails.
This is what I want :

```
"id": 34,
    "title": "Test Page Gallery",
    "featured_image": [
                 "images": [
                     {
                       "id": 12,
                       "title": "test img 2",
                       "image": {
                       "url": "/uploads/medium/image/11/image2.jpeg"
                        }
                     ]
                 ],
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "title": "test img 1",
            "image": {
                "url": "/uploads/image/image/11/image1.jpeg"
        }, ....
     ]
```

This is what I get:

```
"id": 34,
    "title": "Test Page Gallery",
    "featured_image": "[]",
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "title": "test img 1",
            "image": {
                "url": "/uploads/image/image/11/image.jpeg"
        }, ....
     ]
```

Strong params :

```
def page_params
  params.permit(:title, image_ids:[], featured_image: [image_ids:[]])
end
```

Page Model:

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :images, class_name: "Image", join_table: "images_pages"
end
```

I defined the featured_image column as a string but I understand this was probably the wrong thing to do. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you've one of two approaches here:

1) Have two separate associations, specifying the `Image` class name for `featured_images`:

**page.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :images, join_table: "images_pages"
has_and_belongs_to_many :featured_images, class_name: Image, join_table: "featured_images_pages"
```

2) Using a `has_many through` association and having a flag on the join table whether the image is featured or not:

**page.rb**

```
has_many :images, through: :images_pages
has_many :images_pages
```

**images_pages.rb**

```
class ImagesPages
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :page

  scope :featured, -> { where(featured: true) }
end
```

Good quick read on the latter approach [here](https://coderwall.com/p/9xk6ra/rails-filter-using-join-model-on-has_many-through).

I always prefer the flexibility of a `has_many through` relationship.

Have a play with these and see if either helps - any questions, let me know and I'll see how I can customise / expand :)

Comment: This is really helpful thanks, I've had a readup about the has many : through and it definitely seems like a good option. Am I right in thinking I would just need to add another scope on the images_pages.rb model if I wanted , say a "banner image" connection later?

Comment: Yep, spot on :) I'd likely use an [enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) column on the `images_pages` table to keep it simple - something like `enum image_type: [:default, :featured, :banner]`. This will allow you to expand this simply and automatically defines the scopes - make sure the column's an integer, defaults to `0` and has an index. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: Hmmm, this is definitely the way I want to go, but am now getting a "HasManyThroughOrderError Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Page#image' which goes through 'Page#image_page' before the through association is defined." error in the terminal, my code is as above, except plural of images_pages model

Comment: Ignore last comment, error fixed by switching aroung the "has_many" lines in the model

Comment: Glad you're getting there. FYI you might need to update the join table: `has_and_belongs_to_many` requires the table have no `id` column, whereas `has_many through` requires one.

Comment: I ended up generating a new model- "image_page" rather than using the join table, will this^^ still be an issue? I now get no errors but still an empty array returned in the json for "featured image". Sending : `featured_image: [image_ids: Array(1)]` Receiving `featured_image: "[]"`. I feel like this must be because I scaffolded featured image as a string, but cant think how else to do it as array isn't allowed.

Really appreciate you taking the time to help me out mate

Comment: I realised I forgot to accept your answer! thank you very much, the solution, as you said, was to create two extra 'join' models and have two has many through relationships- one for each. this allowed me to create featured images and gallery images fields. Thanks!